# What happens to silicone gaskets (siloxane rubber) in presence of ethylene glycol?

Tags: materials, cooling

Normal sealings and gaskets are made from NBR for use in conjunction with aqueous solutions of ethylene glycol which are common coolants for various purposes.

However to keep sulphur out of a cooling system and the surrounding area I want to change NBR sealings against silicone sealings. I've read some vague information about reduced stability of these sealings in glycol containg coolants. But what is the detailed behaviour? Will it intumesce, brittle or deteriorate otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the available data it looks like it will perform well:

- [efunda.com -  (4) Good, both for static and dynamic seals](http://www.efunda.com/designstandards/oring/oring_chemical.cfm?SM=none&SC=Ethylene%20Glycol)
- [pspglobal.com -  1 = Recommended](http://www.pspglobal.com/fluid-compatibility/chemicals-e.html)

Temperature and additives may change this, however.